# Add a logo to keystonejs navigation bar

Tags: keystonejs

I want to add a logo to a keystone project or if logo is not possible, just a simple text. I was able to add the logo only during the login process. I suppose the best place to add the logo is the navigation bar but its not a must.

I tried to changed the home logo `<span class="octicon octicon-home"></span>` with my logo but was not able to found where.

I tried to add `img(src='/images/logo.png', width='160')` to `templates/layouts/default.pub` but I got an error `img is a self closing element: <img/> but contains nested content.` It's also wrote `There is no .container wrapping class around body blocks to allow more flexibility in design`

I tried to add an iFrame using javascript and tried to put some html code on it. This also didn't worked.

I also tried to set a label or singular to one page but this is not what I need

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can find the default logo in:

\node_modules\keystone\admin\public\images\logo.png

After replace the PNG image, the login screen will reflect the updated logo.

Next for Admin UI, you can check:

\node_modules\keystone\admin\client\App\components\Navigation\Primary\index.js

Line 77:

```
return (
            <PrimaryNavItem
                className={className}
                label="octicon-home"
                title={'Dashboard - ' + brand}
                to={Keystone.adminPath}
            >
                <span className="octicon octicon-home" />
            </PrimaryNavItem>
```

Replace the span with:

```
return (
            <PrimaryNavItem
                className={className}
                label="octicon-home"
                title={'Dashboard - ' + brand}
                to={Keystone.adminPath}
            >
                <img src="/keystone/images/logo.png" width="20" height="20"/>
            </PrimaryNavItem>
```

Finally in public page, edit (if you are using PUG):

\templates\layouts\default.pug

Line 54:

```
a.navbar-brand(href='/')
    img(src='/keystone/images/logo.png' width='20' height='20')
```